# Drive is inactive on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, hard-drive

I am not sure how to explain my problem, so I have attached a pic here.

[image: Drive is inactive]

The drive MULTISTORAGE is inactive. It doesn't show up in MYCOMPUTER. I tried to reformat it, I get an error message "Volume is being used ... .. ."

I am not sure how to get this drive back. Problem is, I do not know if I have saved anything there or not. So, can't just blindly delete the partition and recreate it.

1. What could cause this problem? I did not use any 3rd party app to create this drive
2. How can I view files in this drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking the partition as active should only affect startup. Are you not able to assign a drive letter to the partition with *Change Drive Letter and Paths...*? Doing so would make it visible within My Computer.